# Como criar um Bitmap maior que 9999 pixels

Tags: c#, bitmap

Ao tentar um criar um `Bitmap` percebi que não posso criar com o tamanho que eu queria, eu preciso de uma imagem com ***16581375 x 1***.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(16581375, 1);
image.Save("Path aqui");
```

Quanto tento executar esse código ele me retorna o erro:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'Erro genérico de GDI+.'

Answer (score 1):

Conforme esta [**resposta do SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176435/1518921) esta é uma limitação GDI+ imposta pelo Windows.

"GDI" cria uma visualização do arquivo mapeado por memória para os dados dos pixels do bitmap. Isso o torna muito eficiente, os bitmaps tendem a ser grandes e o MMF ajuda a manter os dados de pixels fora do arquivo de paginação. As páginas RAM podem simplesmente ser descartadas e re-ler do arquivo.

O Windows restringe o tamanho da exibição em um MMF, ou seja, a quantidade de dados no arquivo que podem ser direcionados diretamente, [**conforme documentado neste artigo do MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366542%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> O tamanho de um objeto de mapeamento de arquivo que é suportado por um arquivo nomeado é limitado pelo espaço em disco. O tamanho de uma exibição de arquivo está limitado ao maior bloco contíguo disponível de memória virtual não reservada. Este é no máximo 2GB ou menos de **memória virtual** já reservada pelo processo.

"O maior bloco contínuo disponível" é a restrição em um processo de 32 bits, tende a girar em torno de ~600MB, dar ou receber. O limite de 2GB entra em um processo de 64 bits.

Tecnicamente, o "GDI" pode ignorar este limite ao reescalar a exibição. Mas não, o método `LockBits()` (também muito utilizado internamente) seria ineficiente e muito estranho de usar.

Para usar mapas de bits maiores, você pode usar o sucessor de GDI+ que é o `WIC` ([**Windows Imaging Component**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Disponível em .NET através do namespace `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`.

---

### Limite de memória

O limite do tamanho é devido ao limite da memoria virtual, não tem haver com a quantidade de memoria que tem em sua maquina, lembre-se outros programas e inclusive o windows server (ou seu windows local) já usam boa parte da memória, o que pode estar limitando, veja um exemplo de como saber quanto de memória tem disponivel:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class MemoryAvaliable
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Em Bytes
        using (PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes"))
        {
            long availableMemory = Convert.ToInt64(perfCounter.NextValue());
            Console.WriteLine(availableMemory);
        }

        //Em MB
        using (PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes"))
        {
            long availableMemory = Convert.ToInt64(perfCounter.NextValue());
            Console.WriteLine(availableMemory);
        }
    }
}
```